# WPF: Bind/Apply Filter on Boolean Property

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, filter, collectionviewsource

I want to apply a filter to a `ListBox` accordingly to the `IsSelected` property of a `CheckBox`.

At the moment I have something like this.
**XAML**

```
<CheckBox Name="_filterCheckBox" Content="Filter list" Checked="ApplyFilterHandler"/>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeItems}" />
```

**CodeBehind**

```
    public ObservableCollection<string> SomeItems { get; private set; }

    private void ApplyFilterHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_filterCheckBox.IsChecked.Value)
            CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(SomeItems).Filter += MyFilter;
        else
            CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(SomeItems).Filter -= MyFilter;
    }

    private bool MyFilter(object obj)
    {
        return ...
    }
```

It works but this solution feels like the old-fashioned way (Windows Forms).

**Question:**
Is it possible to achieve this with Bindings / in XAML?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can think of would be to make an `ObjectDataProvider` and two separate `CollectionViewSource` objects in XAML. One view would have the filter applied, the other would not. Then you could bind directly to the `CheckBox.IsChecked` property and use a custom `IValueConverter`. The value converter would have 2 dependency properties- both of type `CollectionViewSource.` These properties might be called, "*UnfilteredItems*" and "*FilteredItems*." In XAML, you would set the unfiltered items property to the `CollectionViewSource` that was unfiltered, and the filtered items property to the one with the filter. The converter logic itself would be simple- if true, return the filtered `CollectionViewSource`, if false, return the unfiltered one.

This solution is not extremely elegant, but it would get the job done. Because `Filter` is not a `DependencyProperty` and can only be specified by an event-handler, our hands are kind of tied on this one. I don't think your solution is a bad one, though.