# WPF: Filter TreeView without collapsing it's nodes

Tags: wpf, treeview, filter

This one is a [follow-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693427/wpf-bind-apply-filter-on-boolean-property) question.

I filter the top level nodes of a `TreeView` control like shown below.

```
private void ApplyFilterHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (_filterCheckBox.IsChecked.Value)
        CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(TopLevelNodes).Filter += MyFilter;
    else
        CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(TopLevelNodes).Filter -= MyFilter;
}
```

.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding TopLevelNodes}">
  ...
</TreeView>
```

When the user applies the filter all nodes get collapsed.

**Question**
How can I hide certain nodes in a tree while retaining the expand state of the other nodes?
Can someone explain, what happens internally on `ICollectionView.Filter += MyFilter`.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In cases such as this [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) is always your friend. I presume that `ICollectionView.Refresh()` is called internally to reflect the changes caused by adding/removing a filter. This effectively re-enumerates the nodes in the `TreeView`.

To compensate for this you can always grab the state of all tree items and re-apply them after a refresh. This may not be the easy solution you were looking for.

You may also want to try to set `MyFilter` once and call `ICollectionView.Refresh()` programmatically. Your `MyFilter` should then filter according to `_filterCheckBox.IsChecked` value. This could make a difference but these are all merely ideas. You must try them yourself.

Comment: "You may also want to try to set MyFilter once and call `ICollectionView.Refresh()` programmatically."
Tried it. It makes no difference.  

I went with your first suggestion and took the long road. ;)

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you use the Reflector to get the tree's state?